# bonestrewn crest word doesn't appear

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just killed the Dragon, following the Bonesstrewn Crest, and climbed the rock to get to the word of Power, but that thing is turned off, or something.

Bottom line is, I cannot complete the missions (that little arrow is always there, and the quest is still on my quest log) and there seems to be no word left for me to learn.

How do I solve this glitch?

Thanks :)
Kath

Answer (score 1):

**Common glitch** if you can load previous game and manage to complete quest consider yourself lucky since in most cases it won't help,and it still isn't fixed by updates.

Possible solutions:

- Save, power on/off, reload(simple but worked for few people).
- Use **player.teachword** console command to learn the shout by force.(Read more details on second link since it brings some other problems to mind).

[Problem Talk 1](http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/52479/t1698674-word-wall-glitch/)

[Problem Talk 2](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Word_Wall)

[Teachword console commands](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Shout_Codes_%28Skyrim%29)

Comment: Reading your source link, none of them say that they stop the quest from being able to be completed except the ones that cite the dragon is unkillable.. Which is not the case here as the dragon is dead but the quest is not marked as complete?

Comment: Hm I misplaced your problem,fixed answer.